# R: Raster data extracted to shapefile added as a matrix - error in writeOGR

Tags: r, spatial, raster, shapefile, r-raster

I have extracted the median value for several raster layers into polygon shapefile using:

```
#read shapefile
huc12 <- readOGR(dsn=gdb1, layer="HUC12_proj")

#read raster
temp.avg <- raster("projected_climate_rasters/temp_avg_copy")

#extract median of raster for each polygon
huc12$Temp.Avg.Med <- extract(temp.avg, huc12, fun = median)
```

I transformed the data to numeric:

```
huc12@data <- transform(huc12@data, Temp.Avg.Med = as.numeric(Temp.Avg.Med))
```

The data appear to have all been attached to the shapefile; however, one of the sets of appended data appears to have been attached as a matrix. For instance,
the Temp.Avg.Med data appears under huc12@data as:

```
.. ..$ Temp.Avg. Med: num [1:877000] 962 ...
```

while another (PET_AnCV) appears as:

```
.. ..$ PET_AnCV : num [1:87700, 1] 94.4 ...
```

I didn't discover this until I attempted to write the new shapefile, which gave the following error:

```
> write_shape(huc12, "huc12")
Error in writeOGR(shp, dir, base, driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE) : 
Can't convert columns of class: matrix; column names: PET_AnCV
```

Any suggestions? (I could not make this reproducible given the data involved and could not reproduce with example shapefiles.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the value-extract from `PET_AnCV` is a matrix instead of a vector. This is normal when you extract values from a multilayer raster, where you get a matrix with a row per feature (*ie.* polygon) and a column per layer. In this case you only have one layer (and column), so you could easily just select the respective column when you're assigning it to the shapefile:

```
vals <- extract(PET_AnCV,huc12)
huc12$PET_AnCV <- vals[,1]
```

But since that's not really the best approach, I'll explain a bit further and give an example:

The error message you're getting tells you that this entire matrix is assigned to one single column of your shapefile's attribute table. This is fine while in R (since it's a slot in a list), but once you're trying to write the file to disk, you run into problems.

Instead of trying to write the extracted values directly to the shapefile, you could use the functionality of the `foreign` package to store your results in your shapefile's `dbf` file. This is a cleaner approach and also gives you more control over what you're doing. If your shapefile is big and/or has many polygons, this will be also much faster.

As for a reproducible example, how's this:

I'm using the Admin-1 borders of Austria (which has 11 distinct polygons) as pendant to your shapefile:

```
# load libraries
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(foreign)

# download shapefile which is used for extraction
huc12 <- getData('GADM', country='AUT', level=1)
```

Here I need to write it to disk since I don't have a dbf file yet. Since you already have it, you can skip this part.

```
# write to disk
writeOGR(huc12,dsn = 'huc12.shp','huc12',driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

Creating a 10 layer rasterbrick with some random values to extract from:

```
# create fake value rasterbrick
ras <- raster()
PET_AnCV <- lapply(1:10,function(x) setValues(ras,runif(ncell(ras))))
PET_AnCV <- do.call(brick,PET_AnCV)
```

Now I'm extracting the values and append them to the dbf file using `cbind`. The variable name will be the column name which corresponds to the layer name of your multilayer raster. If these are generic or not descriptive enough, you can easily change them with `colnames(vals) <- new_name_vector`.

```
# extract values and append to dbf
vals <- extract(PET_AnCV,huc12,fun=median)

dbf <- read.dbf('huc12.dbf')
dbf <- cbind(dbf,vals)
write.dbf(dbf,'huc12.dbf')
```

HTH

Comment: Val: Thanks so much for taking the time! This was very helpful!